# Excel Data overite problem

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, eclipse

I have generate testcases for the login and register page so,i want to display testresult in excel sheet but problem is that when i run testng.xml file then data is overrite into file .i want to display result in multiple sheet in one single workbook
For Register Page:

```
package com.sevenbits.diecast;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;

    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
    import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
    import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    //@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
    public class Register 
    {

        static WebDriver driver;

        String  expectedurl = "http://example.com/account-page/?ihc_register=create_message";

         static HSSFWorkbook workbook;
          static HSSFSheet sheet;
          static Map<String, Object\[\]> testresultdata;

        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup() throws IOException
        {


            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

               sheet = workbook.createSheet("Register");

               testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object\[\]>();
               testresultdata.put("1", new Object\[\] {"TestCasesNo", "UserName","Email","Name","Password","Confirm Password","Expected Result","Actual Result", "Pass/Fail"});

        }

        @Test
        public void a_register()
        {
            driver.get("http://example.com/");
            WebElement regmain = driver.findElement(By.className("reg"));
            regmain.click();
        }

        @DataProvider(name = "Authentication")

          public static Object\[\]\[\] credentials() {

                return new Object\[\]\[\] { { " ", " "," "," "," "}};

          }


        @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
        public void b_blankdata(String uname,String email,String strname,String strpass,String strconpass)
        {
            driver.get("http://example.com//register/");


            WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("user_login"));
            username.clear();
            username.sendKeys(uname);

            WebElement mail = driver.findElement(By.name("user_email"));
            mail.clear();
            mail.sendKeys(email);

            WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("user_Name"));
            name.clear();
            name.sendKeys(strname);

            Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
            se.selectByIndex(3);

            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("pass1"));
            password.clear();
            password.sendKeys(strpass);

            WebElement confirmpassword = driver.findElement(By.name("pass2"));
            confirmpassword.clear();
            confirmpassword.sendKeys(strconpass);

            WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("ihc_submit_bttn"));
            submit.click();

            String actual = driver.getCurrentUrl();

            if(actual.equals(expectedurl))
            {
                Assert.assertTrue(true);
                testresultdata.put("2", new Object\[\] {1d, uname, email,strname,strpass,strconpass,expectedurl,actual ,"Pass"});
            }
            else
            {
                testresultdata.put("2", new Object\[\] {1d, uname, email,strname,strpass,strconpass,expectedurl,actual ,"Fail"});
                Assert.assertTrue(false);

            }

        }
        @DataProvider(name = "Authentication2")

          public static Object\[\]\[\] credentials2() {

                return new Object\[\]\[\] { { "test93", "test93@tristonsoft.com"," test","12Abcd","12Abcd"}};
          }


        @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication2")
        public void d_validdata(String uname,String email,String strname,String strpass,String strconpass)
        {
            driver.get("http://example.com//register/");


            WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("user_login"));
            username.clear();
            username.sendKeys(uname);

            WebElement mail = driver.findElement(By.name("user_email"));
            mail.clear();
            mail.sendKeys(email);

            WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.name("user_Name"));
            name.clear();
            name.sendKeys(strname);

            Select se = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
            se.selectByIndex(3);

            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("pass1"));
            password.clear();
            password.sendKeys(strpass);

            WebElement confirmpassword = driver.findElement(By.name("pass2"));
            confirmpassword.clear();
            confirmpassword.sendKeys(strconpass);

            WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.id("ihc_submit_bttn"));
            submit.click();

            String actual = driver.getCurrentUrl();

            if(actual.equals(expectedurl))
            {
                Assert.assertTrue(true);
                testresultdata.put("4", new Object\[\] {3d, uname, email,strname,strpass,strconpass,expectedurl,actual ,"Pass"});
            }
            else
            {
                testresultdata.put("4", new Object\[\] {3d, uname, email,strname,strpass,strconpass,expectedurl,actual ,"Fail"});
                Assert.assertTrue(false);

            }


        }
         @AfterClass
          public void setupAfterSuite() {
                 Set<String> keyset = testresultdata.keySet();
                    int rownum = 0;
                    for (String key : keyset) {
                        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
                        Object \[\] objArr = testresultdata.get(key);
                        int cellnum = 0;
                        for (Object obj : objArr) {
                            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                            if(obj instanceof Date) 
                                cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                            else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                                cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                            else if(obj instanceof String)
                            {
                                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                                System.out.println(obj);
                            }
                            else if(obj instanceof Double)
                                cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                        }
                    }
            try {



                FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream("E:\\TestResult.xls");
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");


            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


          }

            private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
                try {
                  driver.findElement(by);
                  return true;
                } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                  return false;
                }
              }
    }
```

**For Login Page:**

```
package com.sevenbits.diecast;


import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.TestNGException;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class LoginPage
{

    static WebDriver driver;

    String  expectedurl = "http://example.com/account-page/";

    final String userblank1 = " ";
    final String passblank1 = " ";

    String  userblank2  = "rutvisoni";
    String  passblank2  = "";

     static String s1;

     static HSSFWorkbook workbook1;
      static HSSFSheet sheet;
      static Map<String, Object[]> testresultdata;


    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup()throws TestNGException, IOException
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\Selenium Jar\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

            workbook1 = new HSSFWorkbook();

           sheet = workbook1.createSheet("Login");


        /*WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"));
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet", 0);
           */


            //sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(1);

           testresultdata = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object[]>();
           testresultdata.put("1", new Object[] {"TestCasesNo", "UserName","Password","Expected Result","Actual Result", "Pass/Fail"});

    }


    @Test
    public void login()
    {
        driver.get("http://example.com/");
        WebElement loginmain = driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-14235"));
        loginmain.click();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "Authentication")
      public static Object[][] credentials() {

            return new Object[][] { { " ", " " }};

      }

    @Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")

        public void blankdata(String uname,String Password)
    {

        driver.get("http://example.com//loginregister/");

        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("log"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(uname);

        WebElement pass = driver.findElement(By.name("pwd"));
        pass.clear();
        pass.sendKeys(Password);

        WebElement submit = driver.findElement(By.name("Submit"));
        submit.click();

        String actual = driver.getCurrentUrl();

        if(actual.equals(expectedurl))
        {
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
            testresultdata.put("2", new Object[] {1d, uname, Password,expectedurl,actual ,"Pass"});
        }
        else
        {
            testresultdata.put("2", new Object[] {1d, uname, Password,expectedurl,actual ,"Fail"});
            Assert.assertTrue(false);

        }

    }


     @AfterClass
  public void setupAfterSuite() {
         Set<String> keyset = testresultdata.keySet();
            int rownum = 0;
            for (String key : keyset) {
                Row row = ((Sheet) sheet).createRow(rownum++);
                Object [] objArr = testresultdata.get(key);
                int cellnum = 0;
                for (Object obj : objArr) {
                    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                    if(obj instanceof Date) 
                        cell.setCellValue((Date)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof Boolean)
                        cell.setCellValue((Boolean)obj);
                    else if(obj instanceof String)
                    {
                        cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                        System.out.println(obj);
                    }
                    else if(obj instanceof Double)
                        cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
                }
            }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out =new FileOutputStream(new File("E:\\TestResult.xls"));
        workbook1.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


  }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
}
```

Comment: Multiple sheet in one file . Am I right ?

Comment: Yes but i want to display data into excel sheet from the two java file

Comment: I still have one doubt. Have you write sheet = workbook.createSheet("Login"); tried in Login class?

Comment: yes i have create for the login.i am attaching that file also

Comment: I have tried a lot but it is getting updated after new run from another class

Comment: I have another way to store data in one file.

Comment: how can do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50308/discussion-between-sagar007-and-rutvi-soni).

Comment: It's hard to read your code as large part of import statements is commented out (in between /* */). Can you please edit your question and paste only the necessary part of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual problem is over writing files by Jar on every test class run. Because of this, Program is **not able to store every test data with history.**

There is another way to do it **(store previous excel data)**.

> Create test specific Excel file and combine it.

Please follow below steps.

**Precondition : Create test specific Excel file**

**1. Create below class file in your project : `CopySheets.java`**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet; 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;   
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

    public class CopySheets
    {

    public static Workbook mergeExcelFiles(Workbook book, List<InputStream> inList)
    {
        try
        {
            for (InputStream fin : inList)
            {
                Workbook b = WorkbookFactory.create(fin);
                for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++)
                {
                    // not entering sheet name, because of duplicated names
                    copySheets(book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i)), b.getSheetAt(i));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return book;
    }

    /**
     * @param newSheet the sheet to create from the copy.
     * @param sheet the sheet to copy.
     */
    public static void copySheets(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheet)
    {
        copySheets(newSheet, sheet, true);
    }

    /**
     * @param newSheet the sheet to create from the copy.
     * @param sheet the sheet to copy.
     * @param copyStyle true copy the style.
     */
    public static void copySheets(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheet, boolean copyStyle)
    {
        int maxColumnNum = 0;
        Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, CellStyle>() : null;
        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++)
        {
            Row srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            Row destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);
            if (srcRow != null)
            {
                copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);
                if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum)
                {
                    maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++)
        {
            newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param srcSheet the sheet to copy.
     * @param destSheet the sheet to create.
     * @param srcRow the row to copy.
     * @param destRow the row to create.
     * @param styleMap -
     */
    public static void copyRow(Sheet srcSheet, Sheet destSheet, Row srcRow, Row destRow, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap)
    {
        // manage a list of merged zone in order to not insert two times a merged zone  
        Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddressWrapper>();
        destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
        // reckoning delta rows  
        int deltaRows = destRow.getRowNum() - srcRow.getRowNum();
        // pour chaque row  
        for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++)
        {
            Cell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j); // ancienne cell  
            Cell newCell = destRow.getCell(j); // new cell   
            if (oldCell != null)
            {
                if (newCell == null)
                {
                    newCell = destRow.createCell(j);
                }
                // copy chaque cell  
                copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
                // copy les informations de fusion entre les cellules  
                //System.out.println("row num: " + srcRow.getRowNum() + " , col: " + (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());  
                CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), (short) oldCell.getColumnIndex());

                if (mergedRegion != null)
                {
                    //System.out.println("Selected merged region: " + mergedRegion.toString());  
                    CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow() + deltaRows, mergedRegion.getLastRow() + deltaRows, mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(), mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
                    //System.out.println("New merged region: " + newMergedRegion.toString());  
                    CellRangeAddressWrapper wrapper = new CellRangeAddressWrapper(newMergedRegion);
                    if (isNewMergedRegion(wrapper, mergedRegions))
                    {
                        mergedRegions.add(wrapper);
                        destSheet.addMergedRegion(wrapper.range);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param oldCell
     * @param newCell
     * @param styleMap
     */
    public static void copyCell(Cell oldCell, Cell newCell, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap)
    {
        if (styleMap != null)
        {
            if (oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook())
            {
                newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            }
            else
            {
                int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
                CellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
                if (newCellStyle == null)
                {
                    newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
                    newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
                    styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
                }
                newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
            }
        }
        switch (oldCell.getCellType())
        {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
                newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Récupère les informations de fusion des cellules dans la sheet source pour les appliquer à la sheet destination... Récupère toutes les zones merged dans
     * la sheet source et regarde pour chacune d'elle si elle se trouve dans la current row que nous traitons. Si oui, retourne l'objet CellRangeAddress.
     * 
     * @param sheet the sheet containing the data.
     * @param rowNum the num of the row to copy.
     * @param cellNum the num of the cell to copy.
     * @return the CellRangeAddress created.
     */
    public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++)
        {
            CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
            if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum))
            {
                return merged;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check that the merged region has been created in the destination sheet.
     * 
     * @param newMergedRegion the merged region to copy or not in the destination sheet.
     * @param mergedRegions the list containing all the merged region.
     * @return true if the merged region is already in the list or not.
     */
    private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddressWrapper newMergedRegion, Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions)
    {
        return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);
    }
    }

    class CellRangeAddressWrapper implements Comparable<CellRangeAddressWrapper>
    {
    public CellRangeAddress range;

    /**
     * @param theRange the CellRangeAddress object to wrap.
     */
    public CellRangeAddressWrapper(CellRangeAddress theRange)
    {
        this.range = theRange;
    }

    /**
     * @param o the object to compare.
     * @return -1 the current instance is prior to the object in parameter, 0: equal, 1: after...
     */
    public int compareTo(CellRangeAddressWrapper o)
    {

        if (range.getFirstColumn() < o.range.getFirstColumn() && range.getFirstRow() < o.range.getFirstRow())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (range.getFirstColumn() == o.range.getFirstColumn() && range.getFirstRow() == o.range.getFirstRow())
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }

    }
    }
```

**2. Now in your `@AfterClass` call this lines after writing excel file.**

```
     FileInputStream out1 = new FileInputStream("E:\\Register.xls");

        List<InputStream> strFile = new ArrayList<InputStream>();

        strFile.add(out1);

        Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();

        book = CopySheets.mergeExcelFiles(book, strFile);

        out = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Result.xls", true);

        book.write(out);

        out.close();
```

This will merge your test specific file in `**"E:\\Result.xls"**`

**Alternative :**

**Note : Best Practice is , Please write this code in `@AfterSuite` as Under with all test excel.**

```
    @AfterSuite
public static void endExecution()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Execution is Ended..");
        File loginFile = new File("E:\\Login.xls");
        File registerFile = new File("E:\\Register.xls");
        FileInputStream out1 = null;
        FileInputStream out2 = null;

        if (loginFile.exists())
        {
            out1 = new FileInputStream(loginFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (registerFile.exists())
        {
            out2 = new FileInputStream(registerFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        List<InputStream> strFile = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
        if (out1 != null)
        {
            strFile.add(out1);
        }
        if (out2 != null)
        {
            strFile.add(out2);
        }

        File finalOutputfile = new File("E:\\Result.xls");
        if (finalOutputfile.exists())
        {
            finalOutputfile.delete();
            finalOutputfile.createNewFile();
        }

        Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();

        book = Copysheet.mergeExcelFiles(book, strFile);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(finalOutputfile, true);
        book.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: i am folling above steps but i am getting error in copysheet class

Comment: wait i am attaching screenshot

Comment: Hi it is import error Please import statement correctly.

Comment: ok.problem is solve of import

Comment: Please correct answer if problem is solved.

Comment: i will correct when i will get solution.i am getting another error

Comment: Please let me know the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50360/discussion-between-sagar007-and-rutvi-soni).